# Regex for ASCII printable characters excluding some special characters

Tags: regex

Can someone please help me with the regex for english characters, numbers and excluding few special characters?

The regex should be between ASCII>=32 and <127 and must not include special characters like
` ~ !   $ % ^ & * ( ) + = [ ] { } < > ? ; :  \ |.

I created a simple regex for string only (^\p{L}+$) but how do I include all the characters and numbers but avoid these special ones listed above and others outside that ASCII code?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Instead of allowing "everything except *x*", you should go for a whitelist since you have a defined set of characters that you want to allow.

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z'"#,\-/_ .@]+$
```

Please review the regex, I might have missed some special characters. It should give you the right idea!

Comment: Thanks a lot..
I can certainly do that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
^[\x20-\x7F]+$
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Could you please tell what it does?

Comment: Matches the characters between - \x20 the character   with position 0x20 (32 decimal or 40 octal) in the character set
\x7F the character  with position 0x7F (127 decimal or 177 octal) in the character set